# Can I use the Code First Entities as ViewModels in Entity Framework C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Im getting tired of using Two models.  One model for the database and then one view model for the user.

Im wondering, since I can't find it anywhere else, if I can use the models from the database as view models?  Can I pass the entities from the database and pass them into the views?

Im pretty sure I read somewhere that the entities and connections stay alive within the view while using it.  That was the reason not to use it.

Any clarification on the matter would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im getting tired of using Two models. One model for the database and
>   then one view model for the user.

Interesting design philosphy

> Im wondering, since I can't find it anywhere else, if I can use the
>   models from the database as view models?

Yes, try the MVC view gen templates. You can enter model class and contexts.
If you Web project references your model project, the view generation templates allow you to select from other projects.

> Can I pass the entities from the database and pass them into the
>   views?

yes. Web project can reference a core/model project.
You can call another project.

> Im pretty sure I read somewhere that the entities and connections stay
>   alive within the view while using it. That was the reason not to use
>   it.

The context life cycle is best kept short yes. At least 1 for each request or even multiple contexts per request.
Completely unrelated to the model.  Scaffolding/sample code is best seen as a starter kit.

> Any clarification on the matter would be great!
>   Check the template support / scaffolding etc, in MVC view

A little more reading on the topic might help.